# How do I move iTunes Library to a new drive without losing the 'Date added' field?

Tags: macos, itunes

I've run out of drive space on my external and got a new one to move everything on to. I can't afford to lose my 'date added' values. How is this done? I should mention I let iTunes manage the files for me (in other words - it all lives in one place).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just move your iTunes folder (along with the iTunes library file). The "Date Added" field is stored in the library file (it's an XML file actually, so you can open it with a text editor to verify), and if you move the whole thing lock, stock, and barrel, nothing should change at all.

Comment: How will the OS know that it has been moved and where to look?

Currently, my iTunes folder (with the XML file, lib file and the empty iTunes Music folder etc) lives on the main HD, whereas the actual music (the FULL iTunes Music folder) lives on the dying external drive I want to replace...

Comment: You can do a search and replace in the Library file to replace all links to point to the new place where your music resides. e.g replace *C:\Documents and Settings\Scoopdreams\My Music\iTunes\Old Music* with *E:\New Music Folder*

Comment: assuming that last time your music files are stored in "C:\..\Old Music", and you moved them to "E:\New Music Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Change the Music Folder location in iTunes->Preferences->Advanced to the new, still empty location.  Ensure "Keep iTunes Music folder organized" is checked.

Then, in the iTunes menu, select File->Library->Consolidate Library.  iTunes will move the music to the new folder.
[Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449) will hold your hand through this.